# Best Practices for defining PatternLayout when using Log4j SyslogAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, syslog, owasp

For those who are developing applications that are under PCI scope, where the guidance suggests that you should store your application logs on another tier, remoting to a syslog server elsewhere feels like a best practice.

The question becomes, what should the PatternLayout look like that best enables folks to review their logs at least daily?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how they want to do their log reviews.

I would suggest a slightly different twist.  Flatten the log events to an XML format (e.g. the log4j XMLLayout) and save the resulting XML-fragments.

This can then later be post processed easily, for instance by Log Parser

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/logparser/default.mspx

Comment: Syslog is the standard Unix method to do network logging.  If you want a more native Java way to do this, most logging frameworks have the equivalent functionality in terms of a SocketAppender and a receiving program.